# Google API v3 OAuth2 Service Account Token URL 404 Error

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I'm getting a 404 error when attempting to post to this url:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token

which is referenced in the Google Oauth documentaiton here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatingjwt

Here's a snippet of code in case it helps:

```
Dim tokenRequestURL As String = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token?grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9." & GetJWTclaimSet() & "." & GetJWTsignature()

Dim client As New WebClient()
Dim json = client.DownloadString(tokenRequestURL)
```

**update copied from comment:**

```
    Dim tokenRequestURL As String "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token" 
Dim client As New WebClient() 
Dim params As New Specialized.NameValueCollection 
params.Add("grant_type", "urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer") 
params.Add("assertion", "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9." & GetJWTclaimSet() & "." & GetJWTsignature()) 
Dim responsebytes = client.UploadValues(tokenRequestURL, "POST", params)
```

Comment: are you sure you are trying to POST?  looks like a GET to me.

Comment: @DalmTo I tried `Dim tokenRequestURL As String = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token"
            Dim client As New WebClient()
            Dim params As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
            params.Add("grant_type", "urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer")
            params.Add("assertion", "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9." & GetJWTclaimSet() & "." & GetJWTsignature())
            Dim responsebytes = client.UploadValues(tokenRequestURL, "POST", params)` and I got a 400 bad request error

Comment: If you can read C# you can probably pick apart the code in the client library for this.  Why aren't you using Googles client library?   https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/62c2be7af602ac58ab715426651d15f59786a94f/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/ServiceAccountCredential.cs

Comment: Read the accompanying message to the 400, it will give some clues as to what you are doing wrong.  400 means your client is incorrectly configured, and is different to 404.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solved it ? @DalmTo in OpenIdConnect flow, when the relaying party redirect the userangent to the authorization endpoint, it's should not be a POST but a 302 redirect.